# Creating a new table with grouped data in one row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table[CAT_EXTRACTTIMES] that logs cases waiting to be looked into

```
Wait_Time || Category || TimeLogged
1230      ||     3    || 2024-01-18 23:50:00.0000000
1245      ||     2    || 2024-01-18 23:50:00.0000000
1230      ||     3    || 2024-01-18 23:55:00.0000000
1260      ||     1    || 2024-01-18 23:55:00.0000000
1450      ||     3    || 2024-01-18 00:00:00.0000000
1230      ||     2    || 2024-01-18 00:00:00.0000000
1560      ||     4    || 2024-01-18 00:00:00.0000000
1234      ||     3    || 2024-01-18 00:05:00.0000000
```

I want to create another table grouped by timelogged and categories from the above

```
timelogged                   || cat1    || cat2  || cat3 || cat4 || cat5
2024-01-18 23:50:00.0000000  ||  0      ||  1245 || 1230 || 0    ||   0
2024-01-18 23:55:00.0000000  ||  1260   ||  0    || 1230 || 0    ||   0
2024-01-18 00:00:00.0000000  ||  0      ||  1230 || 1450 || 1560 ||   0
```

I grouped the timelogged and inserted into the table, but not sure how I can bring it to the expected format. I am trying the merge statement but its not bringing all the values in.

```
INSERT INTO CAT_TIMES_CALC(EXTRACTTIME)
SELECT DISTINCT TimeLogged FROM CAT_EXTRACTTIMES

MERGE CAT_TIMES_CALC T
USING CAT_WAIT S ON T.EXTRACTTIME = S.timelogged
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET TCAT_1 =S.Category
```

This was what I tried in the last, to do a merge & update for each category

Comment: can you share the code you tried?

Comment: You need select PIVOT into newtable from old table. Are there only ever 5 categories? And what rule is there that causes 2024-01-18 00:05:00.0000000 to be dropped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either PIVOT or CASE expressions to accomplish this. In my provided example below, I opted for PIVOT.

```
CREATE TABLE #CAT_EXTRACTTIMES (
    Wait_Time int,
    Category tinyint,
    TimeLogged datetime
);

INSERT INTO #CAT_EXTRACTTIMES (Wait_Time, Category, TimeLogged)
VALUES (1230, 3, '2024-01-18 23:50:00.000');

INSERT INTO #CAT_EXTRACTTIMES (Wait_Time, Category, TimeLogged)
VALUES (1245, 2, '2024-01-18 23:50:00.000');

INSERT INTO #CAT_EXTRACTTIMES (Wait_Time, Category, TimeLogged)
VALUES (1230, 3, '2024-01-18 23:55:00.000');

INSERT INTO #CAT_EXTRACTTIMES (Wait_Time, Category, TimeLogged)
VALUES (1260, 1, '2024-01-18 23:55:00.000');

INSERT INTO #CAT_EXTRACTTIMES (Wait_Time, Category, TimeLogged)
VALUES (1450, 3, '2024-01-18 00:00:00.000');

INSERT INTO #CAT_EXTRACTTIMES (Wait_Time, Category, TimeLogged)
VALUES (1230, 2, '2024-01-18 00:00:00.000');

INSERT INTO #CAT_EXTRACTTIMES (Wait_Time, Category, TimeLogged)
VALUES (1560, 4, '2024-01-18 00:00:00.000');

INSERT INTO #CAT_EXTRACTTIMES (Wait_Time, Category, TimeLogged)
VALUES (1234, 3, '2024-01-18 00:05:00.000');

SELECT TimeLogged, ISNULL([1], 0) AS Cat1, ISNULL([2], 0) AS Cat2, ISNULL([3], 0) AS Cat3, ISNULL([4], 0) AS Cat4, ISNULL([5], 0) AS Cat5
FROM (
    SELECT Wait_Time, Category, TimeLogged
    FROM #CAT_EXTRACTTIMES
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
    MAX(Wait_Time) FOR Category IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5])
) AS PivotTable
ORDER BY TimeLogged;

DROP TABLE #CAT_EXTRACTTIMES;
```

Because we are aggregating data, we have to use the MAX() function against Wait_Time to only return a single value. If you ever have more than one value for Wait_Time for a given Category and TimeLogged, you will be missing data.

Microsoft documentation on the use of PIVOT: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: FYI `case` is an *expression* not a *statement*.